# Why don't my custom hibernate dialect detect limitHandler?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-6.x

<hibernate.version>6.2.7.Final</hibernate.version>

```
@Override
public LimitHandler getLimitHandler() {
    return LimitOffsetLimitHandler.INSTANCE;
}
```

I override this method, but I have next sql `offset ? rows fetch first ? rows only`.
If I throw exception, too have next sql `offset ? rows fetch first ? rows only`.

What don't I understand?

It's working for Hibernate 5.*.* but not working for Hibernate 6